# How to dump raw mouse input events

Tags: macos, mouse

I have a Logitech vertical mouse. I can move the mouse and click. The scroll wheel does not register on macOS, neither in Safari, nor Finder, or other.

On Linux, it works like a charm. Therein, I can also use `xev`, and see any mouse panning, click, or scroll, *trivially*.

How can I dump mouse wheel events, at different layers of the stack? Over USB, since it's HID, could just use Wireshark and USB capture… if it's implemented on OS X. But further up?

Comment: `xev` works in macOS as well.  You'll need [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/), but it works.  Also, see if you can boot into Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting) and see if scrolling works there.  I've used Logitechs exclusively for probably the last two decades and never had an issue with the scroll wheel on macOS

Comment: Have you got r he logitech h syst m preference pane from the logitech site?

Comment: No. I was hoping to avoid installing out of tree drivers for something that shouldn't, in principle require it. Basic HID should be part macOS for a while.

I was also hoping to avoid XQuartz since it *may* be a few layers removed from the part of the stack. But then again, I don't know how XQuartz integrates with the rest.

Comment: Logitech are terrible for not using standard structures; I have a similar issue with their MX Master. After years of being able to set up buttons & wheels using SteerMouse or USB Overdrive on my old mouse, I am now stuck using their own inadequate Control Panel instead.